# Using Django chain in template How to?

Tags: database, django, templates

I Used Chain as in :

in views.py

```
places_list = Place.objects.all().order_by('-datetimecreated')[:5]
events_list = Event.objects.all().order_by('-datetimecreated')[:5]
photos_list = Photo.objects.all().order_by('-datetimecreated')[:5]
result_list = list(chain(photos_list, places_list, events_list))
```

In template file

```
    {% for item in result_list %}

        <a href="{% url view_place item.slug %}">{{item.title}}</a>

    {% endfor %}
```

that's to display a place but how to display an event or photo ?

```
        <a href="{% url view_event item.slug %}">{{item.title}}</a>
        <a href="{% url view_photo item.slug %}">{{item.caption}}</a>
```

thanks in advance .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I need to know a bit more to answer your question properly, but here are some ideas that might help you. I'm making the assumption that `photos_list`, `places_list` and `events_list` are all objects of different classes that are Django models.

**Option 1: Define a method on each class that determines the type of the object**

For example, define a `content_type` method on each model, like this:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    def type(self):
        return 'photo'
```

And then check this in your template:

```
{% for item in result_list %}
    {% if item.type == "photo" %}
        ...
    {% elif item.type == "place" %}
        ...
    {% else %}
        ...
    {% end %}
{% endfor %}
```

**Option 2: Define a `render` method on each class**

This is probably much uglier, but you could define a `render` method on each object that returns the complete HTML you want to spit out for that object. Then it's a case of doing this in your template:

```
{% for item in result_list %}
    {{ item.render }}
{% endfor %}
```

**Sidenote: Consider inheritance**

It sounds like photos, places and events are all things that could appear in the same feed, and as such they might share some common fields (like `posted_at`). There are various things you need to consider with regard to this, so it's probably best to look at the [Django documentation on model inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance).

Comment: Hello , thank you for the replay , sorry forget to mention that " photo , event , place " are different models

Comment: My answer assumes that they are different models, so that's fine.

Comment: It does not work on production server : result_list = list(chain(photos_list, places_list, events_list)) is giving : list takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given) !!!

Comment: Have you overridden `list` in the local scope? Check you've not written another method called list anywhere, or included it.

Answer (score 2):

You could define a "proxy" property for each of your models that you can then use to at your template. Consider something like this:

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    ... # fields etc.

    @property
    def url(self):
        ... # return reversed url now

    @property
    def caption(self):
        ... # same idea, access title/whatnot
```

In template it might look something like this:

```
{% for item in item_list %}
    <a href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.caption }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you , first time i try Proxy ... :D

Comment: I don't think you need to make them properties, actually. The template engine will call the method, if it's method.